# Edit the file using sed on the fly and scp on remote host

Tags: linux, shell, sed, scp

I want to use sed to edit few entries in file and in the same command i want to scp on the remote server (passwordless ssh is set up already) ...any clue ?

Comment: basically edit the file *on the fly* using sed and copy it over to remote host.  The original file on local host should remain intact

Comment: I suggest to switch from `scp` to `ssh`.

Comment: The question is unclear. Edit it to make it clear: Tell us what you are trying to achieve, what you have tried, and what went wrong.

Answer (score 1):

For sure there is a better solution, but as an example you could use something like this:

```
echo "blaasdfg\nblaasdfg\nasdfg" >testfile
sed s/bla/foo/g testfile | ssh user@remotehost 'cat - >/tmp/xx'
```

See also this post for the meaning of dash symbol:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3797795/does-mean-stdout-in-bash